# Increment the index value of a List<int>

Tags: c#

I'm trying to add a value to the List index.  I'd like to just increment the current value of the index, but this snippet shows the error.

```
Random random = new Random();

            int[] intArray = new int[10];
            List<int> intList = new List<int>();

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                int randomNumber = random.Next(1, 10);

                intArray[randomNumber] = intArray[randomNumber] + randomNumber;

                // The next line does not add the value of the random number to the List(randomNumber)
                //System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException was unhandled

                intList.Insert(randomNumber, intList[randomNumber]+randomNumber);
            }
```

Using the int[] works.

Answer (score 0):

Because there is no element in the array for your random number,

```
intList[randomNumber]
```

Assume random number is 4, when it get executed first time, it will check for the index 4, which does not have an element.

Also the index starts from 0, change your code like below,

```
intList.Insert(i, randomNumber);
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cant Insert from indexes beyond current list length. and you get `ArgumentOutOfRange` exception.

One way is to initialize your list first. (using linq)

```
List<int> intList = new List<int>(Enumerable.Repeat(0, 10) /*repeat zero 10 times.*/);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating an array of ten integers, and an **empty** list of integers. So the list begins empty and you never `.Add` anything to that list. When you later try to reference to an item of the list, of course you get an exception. So you need to `.Add` some items to your list, or you just can use you integer array in the constructor of the list, so when the List is created will be already filled with the elements of your integer array.

```
Int32[] intArray = new Int32[10];
List<Int32> intList = new List<Int32>(intArray);
```